# Horizontal CSS3 Accordion fixing lag transition

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, accordion, css-transitions

Here is the accordion i edited from other website, and now i trying hard to make it move from right to left, i mean the grey box but i failed to do so, i did tried to change the margin-right of .accordion > ul > li to margin-left but this will make the box missing. any help please. Thank you

**transition from right to left solved and wondering why it's lag, also the menu is not working proper in IE**

http://jsfiddle.net/MxExX/4/

Comment: Do you mean the grey title boxes to be placed on the right when page loads and move to the left on mouseover?

Comment: @neo108         , yes.. that's what i want to do but i could not make it >.<

Comment: Basically you need to adjust the floats, the rotations and the margins. Go through each selector, try to understand what they do and adjust it accordingly. (Understanding, what's going on there is the key)

Comment: @Christoph , i did.. and changed, but it will be missing XD

Answer (score 1):

see, if [THIS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XxbgW/1/) works for you. Might need additional adjusting in IE (/Opera), i tested it in Chrome and FF.

Comment: thank you and it's exact what i want =D but, do you notice that the felling of lag and missing the tab 1 while your mouse is hovering tab 2 ?

Comment: currently editing on this and found it's absolutely not working on IE @.@

Comment: This was just a quick guess I made. I will take a closer look after work.